# Dictionary and content tree permissions removed

Tags: security, deployment

We have a dictionary items which are moved from dev to UAT using Sitecore package installation.

On UAT , the content authors are given explicit permissions on the Dictionary folder. These permissions are not present on the DEV , as the content authors are not created there.

On some occasions, on deployment , the authors permissions got removed. Are we following the correct approach to set the permissions.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior as permissions are part of items. There are stored in Security section in Security field:

[image: Security field]

Switch to 'Raw values' in View Toolbar to see it like above.

As security permissions are part of items, you are effectively replacing values in them during deployment.

It is always best practice to have same roles and permissions on all environments so all features are also testable.

If you are not planning to add roles on all environments then one mitigation could be to use Unicorn or TDS to sync Sitecore items and you will exclude 'Security' field from sync and therefore that field won't be in package and deployed. This is however highly not recommended!